# multi level ordered list

Tags: html, list, html-lists

```
<ol>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b:
        <ol>
            <li>aa</li>
            <li>bb</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>c</li>
</ol>
```

I want to make the counter of the second level to be like `1)` and `2)`, is there any build-in way to do this? I think this should be "ordered list's list-style", but I can't find similar property. I know I can use `counter` related properties, but to use it, I will have to change `<li>` to other container, otherwise, each list item will display two counters.

Answer (score 0):

Try making first list under ul tag, and rest of the list in ol.

```
 <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b:
        <ol>
            <li>aa</li>
            <li>bb</li>
        </ol>
        <li>c</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your list to be multi-leveled, just add the missing closing li tag.

```
<ol>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b:
        <ol>
            <li>aa</li>
            <li>bb</li>
        </ol>
    </li> <!-- this was missing -->
    <li>c</li>
</ol>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/exdv3h2x/).

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you didnt closed `<li>` tag before starting `<li>` for `c`, **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/39map70e/)**

```
<ol>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b:
        <ol>
            <li>aa</li>
            <li>bb</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>c</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing an `<li>` closing tag. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8uz1dc5n/)